# Write simple rails code better

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I'm newbie on rails.

In my form I get string like "123, xxx_new item, 132, xxx_test "

if the item start with "xxx_" than its mean that i should add the item to the db otherwise enter the value

this is my code and i sure that there is a better way to write this code

```
tags = params[:station][:tag_ids].split(",")
    params[:station][:tag_ids] = []   
    tags.each do |tag|
      if tag[0,4]  =="xxx_" 

        params[:station][:tag_ids] << Tag.create(:name => tag.gsub('xxx_', '')).id

      else 

        params[:station][:tag_ids]<< tag   

      end
    end
```

I'm looking for how to improve my code syntax

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
tags = params[:station][:tag_ids].split(',')
params[:station][:tag_ids] = tags.each_with_object([]) do |tag, array|
  array << tag.start_with?('xxx_') ? Tag.create(name: tag[4..-1]).id : tag
end
```